# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory

im getting this error in `if val_loss < least_val_loss:`

this is the rest of that code block

```
least_val_loss = float('inf')
least_loss_model= None
epochs=100
for num_nodes in [16,32,64]:
  for dropout_prob in [0,0.2]:
    for lr in [0.01,0.005, 0.001]:
      for batch_size in [32,64,128]:
        print(f"{num_nodes} nodes, dropout {dropout_prob}, lr {lr}, batch_size{batch_size}")
        model,history = train_model(X_train, y_train, num_nodes,dropout_prob, lr, batch_size,epochs)
        plot_history(history)
        #plot_accuracy(history)
        val_loss = model.evaluate(X_valid,y_valid)
        if val_loss < least_val_loss:
          least_val_loss=val_loss
          least_loss_model=model
```

Answer (score -2):

try

`val_loss = model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)[0]`

Comment: Why would you only get a single element instead of summing over the losses or taking the average (or squared average) or similar?